# Truncated response variable in boosted regression trees

Tags: regression, truncation, boosted-regression-trees

I was thinking about the differences in approaches between parametric and non-parametric statistics in regression.

I am working with a non-negative integer response $N$ with $N\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$.

Let's imagine I wanted to use a boosted regression tree to model this quantity. This regression tree would give me
$$\mathbb{E}[N|X]$$
as output.

But now consider that I wanted to decompose this model into further subcomponents as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N|X]&=\text{Pr}(N>0|X)\cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[N|X,N>0]}_{\text{New model}}
\end{align}
$$
which would mean I am now working with the truncated expectation.

> **My question is**, what would need to change in the boosted regression tree to accommodate this new specification?

If I were working with more traditional parametric approaches (GLM, GAM, GAMLSS) I would simply alter the distribution assumed in the model (a zero-truncated distribution in this case). It's not immediately clear to me how the tree regression would change given the truncation. Is it achieved by changing the loss function?

I understand the tree regression would adapt its estimation due to the zeros not being included in the data, but that certainly wouldn't prevent predictions from being zeros as there is no restriction of the support?